# How to convert a string into a hexadecimal and store that hexadecimal value into a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, hex

I want to store the hex values into a string, but I don't know to do that when my string is not giving me the hex values when it is printed out. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with hex, but I don't know how to get those int values that print out the correct hex values to be stored into a string without it being changed.

I tried different ways of manipulating this and searched on the web but have not found much of a solution in solving this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::hex;
using std::stringstream;

using namespace std;

int main(){
        string s2 = "HelloWorld";

        cout << "string: " << s2 << endl;
        cout << "hexval: ";
        vector<int> character; // converting each character to its ascii value
        string bytes;
        for(int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++) {
            character.push_back(int(s2[i]));
            bytes = to_string(character.at(i));
            cout << hex << character.at(i) << " ";
            cout << bytes << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << bytes << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output that 'bytes' my string is printing out:

```
48 72
65 101
6c 108
6c 108
6f 111
57 87
6f 111
72 114
6c 108
64 100
```

Left is the hexadecimals and right is the string. Two different values. How can I store these hexadecimals that is being converted from a string be stored into a string as a hexadecimal value?

Comment: Perhaps you could share an example of how you want this to work? It's not clear to me what you mean by "store the hex values into a string".

Comment: @lurker I convert the string of "hello world" into a hexadecimal, well from there I want to take that hexadecimal and store that into a string. That's the issue I'm having as it is not storing that hexadecimal value accurately into a string.

Comment: A quick look at [`std::to_string` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) will show that `std::sto_string` has no overload that takes a `char`. But since `char` implicitly converts to `int`, the `int` overload is used and converts the character to its numeric value.

Comment: @user4581301 Are you saying there's no solution to this in the way that I have it then?

Comment: Not this way, unfortunately. See if your compiler supports [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars). It allow you to set the base.

Comment: @user4581301 It does not. Is there any way that we can have those hexadecimal values be converted into a string?

Comment: If you don't have `std::to_chars`, you can do it the old fashioned way like `cout << hex << character.at(i)`, but with a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) in place of `cout`. Once you've got the character converted to hex in the stream, you use the `std::stringstream:: str` method to get the `string` out of the stream.

Comment: @user4581301 Good thinking. I will try that and see if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 different ways:

The first one uses a `char` array and writes to it with `sprintf` with `%X`.

The second way uses a `stringstream` and streams the `int` values into it with the `hex` specifier. You can get the string with the `.str()` method of `stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::hex;
using std::stringstream;

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s2 = "HelloWorld";

    cout << "string: " << s2 << endl;
    string result;
    for(int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++) {
        char buffer[20];
        sprintf(buffer, "%X ", s2[i]);
        result += buffer;
    }
    cout << "hexval1: " << result << endl;

    stringstream res;
    for (int val : s2)
        res << hex << val << " ";

    cout << "hexval2: " << res.str() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not much of a huge expert on C++ so my only question for this is with the res.str, could I create a string lets just say "message" and store res.str() into message? I'm just curious, I might stick with approach number one.

Comment: Yes `string message = res.str();` does that.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Comment: To keep this question up to date with c++17: `std::to_chars(bytes.data(), bytes.data()+2, character.at(i), 16);` Need to presize `bytes` with at least two characters (`string bytes = "XX";` will do the job) and include `<charconv>`.